# secure video urls not working in jwplayer React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, jwplayer

I am working on a project in which I have to show videos from JW Player. If I disable the secure video URLs, videos are playing fine. But the only problem is that in elements tab user can view the media URLs which are downloadable. I tried adding Player ID in my index.html as the [documentation](https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/docs/jw8-add-a-player-library) suggests to play the videos while secure urls settings is enables from JW Player settings, but videos are not playable. Is there any way I can secure the videos or I can enable the secure video urls from JW Player settings, and make the videos playable.

I am using **react-jw-player** libray to play the videos.

```
<ReactJWPlayer
  playerId="4t0kowmP"
  playerScript="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/4t0kowmP.js"
  playlist="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/Ivd4HcO6"
  controls={false}  
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off your question, it's not entirely clear what you are doing exactly, but I'm guessing that your end goal is to have your videos be "private" meaning that only specific users can play.

Looking around the JWP docs, it seems that you need to make sure you follow this: https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/docs/jw8-enable-aes-decryption

I haven't found any other articles about secure videos.

You can also make your life easier by using any other API out there for hosting and delivering videos. For example, api.video:

https://docs.api.video/docs/video-access-management-getting-started-with-private-videos

Comment: Hi, please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's better to mantain original approach while answering, if possible of course. Other libraries seem to be off topic here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure the videos to stop copying etc, the usual industry approach is to use encryption and a DRM system for secure key exchange.

JWPlayer supports DRM - documentation is available here: https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/reference/drm

It's worth being aware that DRM will not stop someone recording the screen with a camera and that there are DRM vulnerabilities reported from time to time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me how can i use encryption? Should I encrypt the url directly in my application before passing it to the ReactJWPlayer library. I guess it will still show the original.

Comment: Actually it is the video itself which is encrypted, not the URL. The link above explains how to use DRM with JWPlayer. If you want just to protect the URL then take a look at their token signing: https://docs.jwplayer.com/platform/docs/protection-enable-url-token-signing